# Performing fuzzy matching

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, fuzzy-logic

In my requirement i need to match names from table to another table.

Source table might contain names as `Tony, Bill, Rob`

Target Table might contain names as `Anthony, William, Robert`

Basically source table may contain nick/short names.

Is there any fuzzy logic/AI tool available in Java/SQL to perform such matches.

I know it can be done using SQL sever fuzzy logic package, but this package comes with SQL server Enterprise Edition, and my client doesnt want to upgrade to it.

Is there any other alternative, preferably open source/free of cost.

Comment: Why the down vote? Do you need any other info let me know

Answer (score 0):

Search frameworks like Apache Lucene provides Fuzzy matching queries. Try FuzzyQuery from Lucene